# How can I prepare an input message for openssl's MD4?

Tags: c, openssl

You know that when you run `openssl` speed for `MD4`, it works for different sizes of input messages: 16, 64, 256, 1024, 8192. I would like to do the same within my code calling `MD4` function directly but I don't really know how can I prepare a message to have a given size. Lets say, I would like to compute `MD4` for 512 or 1024 input. How can I prepare this input?

I have some code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char digest[MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char string[] = "hello";

    MD4((unsigned char*)string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)digest);

    for(int i = 0; i < MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Am I right, that in my example, input size for `MD4` is `6 (string length) * 8 (char size) = 48` size? If so, how can I prepare a message which I will use as input in MD`enter code here`4?

I have some thoughts:

1. I want to give to `MD4` an input message of `512 size`. Should I prepare it like this:

   char txt[64];
       for(int i=0; i<512/8; i++)
       {
           txt[i] = (char)i;
       }

and then run `MD4` like this:

```
`MD4`((unsigned char*)string, strlen(text), (unsigned char*)digest);
```

1. I want to give to md4 an input message of 1024 size. Should I prepare it like this:

   char txt[128];
           for(int i=0; i<1024/8; i++)
           {
               txt[i] = (char)i;
           }

and then run `MD4` like this:

```
MD4((unsigned char*)string, strlen(text), (unsigned char*)digest);
```

Comment: First of all, drop the address-of operators to get rid of the UB. Then we can talk.

Comment: @H2CO3: what do you mean by UB? Nah, nevermind, found the answer on google what UB means ;)

Comment: Very good! Now, my question is: what exactly do you mean by "preparing"? Do you need to copy input and/or the output of the hashing?

Comment: @H2CO3: basicly, I would like to do the same thing that openssl speed does. I mean, it doesnt care what exactly input message is, it only cares about its size. When you run it, it computes for example, md4, for different sizes of input messages: 16, 64, 256, 1024, 8192. I would like to do the same thing, except that I can pass to it a different size of input, no matter what the input exactly is (is it 'hello world' or 'blablablablablabla .... etc') I care only about inputs size :)